# Lua equivalent of virtualenv?

Tags: lua, virtualenv

Is there something like python's virtualenv in lua?

So I can install all required lua modules/rocks in a sandboxed environment.  This is good for test, since I will not mess up with system-wide lua modules or another lua project's environment.

luarocks looks promising since its support of [self-contained installation](http://luarocks.org/en/Installation_instructions_for_Unix).  But I'm interested that if there is some tool like virtualenv which automates the creation, maintenance and switch of sandboxed environments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be fairly simple to switch between Lua installs by setting the `LUA_PATH` environment variable. Quoting [this page](http://www.lua.org/pil/8.1.html) from the Lua documentation:

> To determine its path, require first checks the global variable LUA_PATH. If the value of LUA_PATH is a string, that string is the path. Otherwise, require checks the environment variable LUA_PATH.
>
> [...]
>
> The components in a path are separated by semicolons (a character seldom used for file names in most operating systems). For instance, if the path is
>
> > ?;?.lua;c:\windows\?;/usr/local/lua/?/?.lua
>
> then the call require"lili" will try to open the following files:
>
> > lili
> >       lili.lua
> >       c:\windows\lili
> >       /usr/local/lua/lili/lili.lua

Answer (score 6):

[archived] Have you tried [LuaDist](https://github.com/LuaDist)?

It solves exactly this issue by using so called 'deployments' - it is a single directory in which all dependencies and libraries (and even Lua interpreter) are installed, independent of the whole system.

Comment: This seems to not exist anymore in June 2022

Answer (score 4):

It looks like [vert](https://github.com/aconbere/vert) is what you are looking for.
Like `virtualenvwrapper` in Python, it allows you to define a self-contained Lua environment.
Furthermore, it is available from *luarocks*.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score -1):

In Lua 5.1 there is the environment table, which you can put in global variables and then load strings or files with that table as _G, encapsulating that file.